# Are "how do I begin with XYZ" questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are "how do I begin with XYZ" questions on topic here?

They have appeared before, but I'm not sure they're really suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find answers to such questions valuable for my own reading provided the person answering lists at least one reference I can go to for more information and explains why those references are relevant.

It is not always clear what one should be reading first to understand a new topic. It is also easy to give up in frustration.  Hopefully a good answer helps avoid that frustration for someone.

I think such questions are on-topic and I would not vote to close them.